# Are gmail replies using the same compose paradigm?

Tags: gmail

The new gmail compose experience has advantages but also drawbacks, the most obvious being the fact that it uses different paradigms for new emails and for replies. Let me explain: if I click the compose button, I get a pop-up window on the right corner of the screen which is OK, since I can browse other emails or web content without loosing the composition context. But when I choose the reply option, the compose window uses the old composition style, i.e.: gets mingled in the middle the mail text. This gets even worst when replying in the context of a conversation.

So my question is: 1) why using two different styles of composition, and 2) is there a way to reply using the same style.

N.B.: I've seen replies to this question that suggest pressing Shift and click Reply: this is not a solution, because in this case I get a new browser window with the same garbled text, and *not* the compose pop-up.

Comment: We can't answer the "why" part of your question. Only Google could provide you with the logic behind their design decisions.

Comment: Ok, I understand... What about the second part? Is there a way to force it?

Comment: Without using shift-reply and opening a new browser window? Not that I've found, no.